# How to clear cache Android

Tags: android, list, caching, lazy-evaluation

I need to find a way how to clear the data which my application stores in cache.Basically I am using Fedor's ( [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) ) lazy list implementation and I want to clear the cache automatically when I have for example 100 images loaded.Any ideas how to do that?

**EDIT:**
Code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    deleteCache(this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: Hello, have u got the answer? I have same issue as you. i want clear cache to load new images. thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

this will delete cache

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: call this method by  deleteCache(this);

Comment: how you know if cache deleted?

Comment: Because I think if the cache is deleted the images will start loading again,but they don't.That's the goal that I want to achieve.

Comment: after deleted cache, try to call reload images. if cache deleted go to see in your file explorere->data->data->package name, the cache dir will be empty. if you are running in phone device go and see your manage applications the cache will be 0.00

Comment: sry but I can't get this thing to work.I'm pretty sure I miss something very little and stupid but...

Comment: after called deleteCache(this); call adapter.notifyDataSetChanges(); this will reload images if cache doesn't have images.

Comment: I update the question with the code I'm using,and still can't see the reloading...

Comment: i think you are doing mistake in loading images not in deleting cache memory.

Comment: please tell me how to delete cache of other application in android

Comment: note that if you used the external cache, you'd have to replace `context.getCacheDir()` with `context.getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: I think this has to be done from a class which extends Application in order to get the applications context... might be wrong though

Answer (score 4):

I hope this helps you in getting further

```
public static void trimCache(Context context) {
    File dir = context.getCacheDir();
    if(dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()){
        File[] children = dir.listFiles();
        if (children == null) {
            // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
        } else {
            File temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                temp = children[i];
                temp.delete();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not add tag lines or signatures to your posts. Your name with a link to your profile is automatically displayed at the bottom of every question or answer that you write.

Answer (score 2):

you can call system service **clearApplicationUserData()** ( working only for >= KitKat version )

so you can do a check for version and then everything will go fine :) 
here is the code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            ((ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .clearApplicationUserData();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In addition to providing information for what to do when using KitKat or greater, please also include information for users using a lower version.

Comment: Actually this portion of code crashes my application completely.

Comment: This method is for clear **all the app's data**, not the app's cache! According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086256/2416369), it is expected that the application will close, because this method resets the application completely, so the application needs not to be running...

Answer (score 0):

If using Apache Commons IO, you can accomplish this with a single line (excluding try-catch):

```
try {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(context.getCacheDir());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do some error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin you can just call

```
File(context.cacheDir.path).deleteRecursively()
```

Same result as the other answers, but no need for the checks and looping through manually

Answer (score -4):

Discard old adapter and attach the listview to a new instance of the adapter (listview will lose scroll position, though). Example:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    m_adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) getView()
                .findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        listView.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    }
}
```