# Clear Application cache on exit in android

Tags: android, caching

What I want to do is to clear the cache memory of application on exit of application.

this task i can do manually by this steps.

**< Apps --> Manage Apps --> "My App" --> Clear Cache>>**

but i wants to do this task by programming on exit of application.. please help me guys..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear cache Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898090/how-to-clear-cache-android)

Answer (score 14):

To clear Application Data Please Try this way. I think it help you.

```
public void clearApplicationData() 
{
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
{
    if (dir != null &amp;&amp; dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful answer. but my concern is that when i should call this method  because i am having lots of confusion on timing of calling of this method

Comment: In your application there will be an activity in which the user exits(usually the main activity), override the OnDestroy() and call the above clear cache code.

Answer (score 3):

Just a clarification, the answers work properly except you have to pass the Application context to ***trimCache*** instead of the Activity context (to avoid memory leak), since ***trimCache*** is an static method.

```
 @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      try {
         trimCache(getApplicationContext()); //if trimCache is static
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

However, otherwise, you can make ***trimCache*** non-static and there is no need to pass any Context.

```
public void trimCache() {
   try {
     File dir = getCacheDir();
     if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        deleteDir(dir);
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO: handle exception
  }
}
```