# Cache memory of android application

Tags: android, performance, caching, out-of-memory

I always get the `OutOfMemory` exception.

I know the issue is the Bitmap capacity I downloaded from server to my application already exceeded the cache memory.

But I don't know how much the `Maximum Cache Memory of my application I can stored (images)`is?

People who know,

Please tell me,

Thanks,

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761679/memory-cache-in-android

Comment: Did you reffer https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html?  This page is very informative.

Comment: and look at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#RestrictingMemory which describes your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from doc:

> Mobile devices typically have constrained system resources. Android
>   devices can have as little as 16MB of memory available to a single
>   application. The Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD),
>   Section 3.7. Virtual Machine Compatibility gives the required minimum
>   application memory for various screen sizes and densities.
>   Applications should be optimized to perform under this minimum memory
>   limit. However, keep in mind many devices are configured with higher
>   limits. Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images
>   like photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes
>   photos up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap
>   configuration used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3
>   onward) then loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory
>   (2592*1936*4 bytes), immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some
>   devices.

and although per app limit is different from device to device but I think it is around 16-25 MB.

what should you do?

first you must store your images on the **disk**, then use function below to decode it and then assign it to what imageview you like:

I have changed the function from the doc to read images from file not from resource folder.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filePath,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}
```

just call `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filePath,int reqWidth, int reqHeight)`.

Reference:

[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

another option is using image downloader library, for comparison look at:

[Local image caching solution for Android: Square Picasso vs Universal Image Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995007/local-image-caching-solution-for-android-square-picasso-vs-universal-image-load)

they just take care of most of your problems.