# Clearing Cache in android App Programmatically

Tags: android, performance, caching

I need one help regarding cache memory in my android app. I am Running server (android) in a device. I want to do clear cache of that app programmatically. I have database in that server. Based on that database my client operations are going on. So I don't want it (Database) to get effected. I just want to clear cache not to clear data. Please help me with this.

Comment: If you are using Kotlin see my answer at the bottom for a oneliner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle *) {
      super.onCreate(*);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop(){
      super.onStop();
   }

   //Fires after the OnStop() state
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      try {
         trimCache(this);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void trimCache(Context context) {
      try {
         File dir = context.getCacheDir();
         deleteDir(dir);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
      if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
         String[] children = dir.list();
         for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
               return false;
            }
         }
         return dir.delete();
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

On Kotlin you can just call

```
File(context.cacheDir.path).deleteRecursively()
```

Comment: This one line of code works perfectly in Kotlin.

Comment: When I use this code, I see "Unresolved reference: context"

Comment: @manjesh23 you need to get the context from somewhere (if you are outside of an activity), you need to pass it to the method. You can also try "this" instead of context or "this@YourActivity" for example

Answer (score 3):

Code for clearing the cache:

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }  else if (dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908638/5184092