# Unable to Clear Cache memory programmatically Android

Tags: java, android

I have tried to clear cache memory through button in my application by using below code.
 **activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete Cache"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Retrive Data"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
TextView t1;
EditText et1;
Button b1,b2,b3;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private static MainActivity instance;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    settings = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor= settings.edit();
    instance=this;
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putString("editText",et1.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            t1.setText(settings.getString("editText",null));
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t1.setText("");
            MainActivity.getInstance().clearApplicationData();
                        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t1.setText(settings.getString("editText",null));
        }
    });
}
public static MainActivity getInstance(){ return instance;}
public void clearApplicationData(){
        File cache= getCacheDir();
        File appDir=new File(cache.getParent());
        if(appDir.exists()){
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for(String s: children){
                if(!s.equals("lib")){
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir,s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/ " + s +" DELETED");
                }
            }
        }
}
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}}
```

**Explanation:**
While clicking *Save* button the value typed in EditText will be saved in *Shared Preference*.While clicking *Delete Cache* written code for deleting cache memory with [Refer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977288/clear-application-cache-on-exit-in-android), [Refer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492956/clearing-cache-in-android-app-programmatically).While clicking *Retrive* value stored in *Shared Preference* will be retrieved and displayed in TextView.

**Issue:** While clicking the *Delete Cache* in my logcat its showing that *cache memory deleted* and *shared_prefs deleted* but my cache memory size not reduced. While clicking *Retrive* the value from *Shared Preference* is retriving and showing up in *TextView* but value should be deleted.

**My logcat:**

```
01-09 17:02:26.872 24290-24290/? I/TAG: File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/ cache DELETED
01-09 17:02:26.872 24290-24290/? I/TAG: File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/ shared_prefs DELETED
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onStop() and onDestroy() methods include into your Activity.  Your Activity  **onDestroy()** add following code

```
 @Override
  protected void onStop(){
  super.onStop();
   }
 // after the OnStop() state


  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  try {
     trimCache(this);
      } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
```

and then add following  methods

```
 public static void trimCache(Context context) {
  try {
     File dir = context.getCacheDir();
     if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        deleteDir(dir);
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }

 public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
  if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
     String[] children = dir.list();
     for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
        if (!success) {
           return false;
        }
     }
  }

  // The directory is now empty so delete it
  return dir.delete();
 }
```

Comment: I want to clear cache while clicking button. I replaced  your trimCache() and dleteDir(). still no Improvement

Comment: did you include onDestroy()  in your activity?

Comment: I douted onDestroy() is needed! to call trimCache() inside onClick()? but I don't want to close my activity.

Comment: your activity also in cache memory during the process... if you not close activity means how its clear cache?.understand my point?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.I included `onDestroy()` but still no improvement.while opening the activity again it retriving the data.