# Android Spotify SDK: Clearing the storage/cache

Tags: android, spotify

I'm developing an app using the Spotify SDK.  I noticed the total storage for the app grows pretty quickly after playing a few songs.

I am guessing this is because the songs are being cached.

Is there a way to clear the music cache using the Spotify SDK APIs?

I haven't come across anything in the documentation yet. If I clear it from the settings page, it clears all app data.  The Spotify app seems to have a way to do it but I haven't found an API yet.

Comment: Could this be of use to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically

Comment: are you calling Spotify.destroyPlayer(this); from onDestroy of your Activity or Fragment code when you are done with playing song? Because as per API Documentation of Spotify, If you do not call Spotify.destroyPlayer when you are done with the Player, then your app will leak resources. Here is the link:https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I can confirm destroyPlayer is called when the app exits.  I'm just wondering if this behaviour is normal operation.  Google Play Music storage also grows.

Comment: There is a solution to this.  Just add the line playerConfig.useCache(false); when configuring the player.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and @user3509131,s comment solved it for me. 
Adding it as an answer for someone who might come looking.

The default max cache storage for Spotify SDK is 1024mb and `useCache` is set it True.

You can change it by adding the following line where you configure the Spotify player
   `playerConfig.useCache(Boolean.FALSE)`