# code to Clear Application cache on exit in android

Tags: java, android

its my activity code ! how can i clear all app cache when exit.(like images and data)
can some bosy help me how can i do that ?
when user eclose my app all cache will be deleted automaticaly .
its important to me .

```
package app.tabb;
import co.ronash.pushe.Pushe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import app.tabb.data.AppConfig;
import app.tabb.data.DatabaseHandler;
import app.tabb.data.SharedPref;
import app.tabb.fragment.FragmentCategory;
import app.tabb.utils.Tools;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;



public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    //for ads
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    private ImageLoader imgloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public ActionBar actionBar;
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    private int cat[];
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private SharedPref sharedPref;
    private RelativeLayout nav_header_lyt;

    static ActivityMain activityMain;


    ArrayList<String> slides;
    ImageView imageView;
    Custom_ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;




    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activityMain = this;

        if (!imgloader.isInited()) Tools.initImageLoader(this);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
        Pushe.initialize(this,true);

        prepareAds();
        initToolbar();
        initDrawerMenu();
        prepareImageLoader();
        cat = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.id_category);

        // first drawer view
        onItemSelected(R.id.nav_featured);
        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_nav_featured));

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivitySearch.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // for system bar in lollipop
        Tools.systemBarLolipop(this);
        viewFlipper = (Custom_ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vf);

        slides = new ArrayList<>();
        slides.add("http://www.bargnegar.ir/banner/1.jpg?");
        slides.add("http://www.bargnegar.ir/banner/2.jpg?");
        slides.add("http://www.bargnegar.ir/banner/3.jpg?");
        slides.add("http://www.bargnegar.ir/banner/4.jpg?");
        slides.add("http://www.bargnegar.ir/banner/5.jpg?");
        int i = 0;
        while(i<slides.size())
        {
            imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(slides.get(i),imageView);
            viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
            i++;

        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));
        viewFlipper.setPaintCurrent(paint);
        paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,android.R.color.white));
        viewFlipper.setPaintNormal(paint);

        viewFlipper.setRadius(6);
        viewFlipper.setMargin(4);


        CustomGestureDetector customGestureDetector = new CustomGestureDetector();
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ActivityMain.this, customGestureDetector);

        viewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }



    class CustomGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            // Swipe left (next)
            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.left_in);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.left_out);

                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }else if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.right_in);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.right_out);

                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }

            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.left_in);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.left_out);

            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

    }









    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        Tools.setActionBarColor(this, actionBar);
    }

    private void initDrawerMenu() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                updateFavoritesCounter(navigationView, R.id.nav_favorites, db.getFavoritesSize());
                showInterstitial();
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                actionBar.setTitle(item.getTitle().toString());
                return onItemSelected(item.getItemId());
            }
        });

        // navigation header
        View nav_header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        nav_header_lyt = (RelativeLayout) nav_header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_lyt);
        nav_header_lyt.setBackgroundColor(Tools.colorBrighter(sharedPref.getThemeColorInt()));
        (nav_header.findViewById(R.id.menu_nav_setting)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySetting.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        (nav_header.findViewById(R.id.menu_nav_map)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMaps.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            doExitApp();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySetting.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.action_rate) {
            Tools.rateAction(ActivityMain.this);
        } else if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            Tools.aboutAction(ActivityMain.this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onItemSelected(int id) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        switch (id) {
            //sub menu
            case R.id.nav_all:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, -1);
                break;
            // favorites
            case R.id.nav_favorites:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, -2);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_atolie:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[0]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_arayesh:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[1]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_behdashti:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[2]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_safar:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[3]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_peyk:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[4]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_bank:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[5]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_pooshak:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[6]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_sukht:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[7]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_khodro:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[8]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_food:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[9]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_featured:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[10]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_zanjirei:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[11]);

                break;
            case R.id.nav_ghanadi:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[12]);

                break;
            case R.id.nav_coffeshop:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[13]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_ketring:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[14]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_tourismcenter:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[15]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_shop:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[16]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_hospital:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[17]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_mobl:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[18]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_mobile:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[19]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_sport:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[20]);

                break;

            case R.id.nav_hotels:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[21]);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_khanegi:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[22]);
                break;

            default:
                break;


            /* IMPORTANT : cat[index_array], index is start from 0
             */
        }


        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            //initToolbar();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    private long exitTime = 0;

    public void doExitApp() {
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - exitTime) > 2000) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.press_again_exit_app, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void prepareImageLoader() {
        Tools.initImageLoader(this);
    }

    private void showDialogGPS() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("مکان یابی خودکار");
        builder.setMessage("سرویس مکان یابی دیوایس شما فعال نیست . جهت استفاده بهتر از برنامه لطفا آن را فعال کنید.");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("فعال کردن", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("نادیده گرفتن", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override


    protected void onResume() {
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(!enabled) {
            showDialogGPS();
        }

        if (!imgloader.isInited()) Tools.initImageLoader(this);
        updateFavoritesCounter(navigationView, R.id.nav_favorites, db.getFavoritesSize());
        if (actionBar != null) {
            Tools.setActionBarColor(this, actionBar);
            // for system bar in lollipop
            Tools.systemBarLolipop(this);
        }
        if (nav_header_lyt != null) {
            nav_header_lyt.setBackgroundColor(Tools.colorBrighter(sharedPref.getThemeColorInt()));
        }
        super.onResume();
    }


    private void updateFavoritesCounter(NavigationView nav, @IdRes int itemId, int count) {
        TextView view = (TextView) nav.getMenu().findItem(itemId).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.counter);
        view.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }

    private void prepareAds() {
        // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        //prepare ads
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest2);
    }

    /**
     * show ads
     */
    public void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready
        if (AppConfig.ADS_MAIN_INTERSTITIAL && mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }


    public static ActivityMain getInstance() {
        return activityMain;
    }

    public static void animateFab(final boolean hide) {
        FloatingActionButton f_ab = (FloatingActionButton) activityMain.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        int moveY = hide ? (2 * f_ab.getHeight()) : 0;
        f_ab.animate().translationY(moveY).setStartDelay(100).setDuration(400).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override your onDestroy() method in your activity and invoke some method that removes cache directory. 
How to do it? [Clear Cache in Android Application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically)