# My App is gaining Cache data up to 40MB, how to realase that data?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have very simple app which is parsing `JSON` data through `Google Volley`, puts it in `ArrayList` of objects and then fetching that in `RecyclerView`. And that is all, very simple, no extra functions, no shared preferences, nothing except implementation of that `RecyclerView` endless scrolling solution: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

And while I'm scrolling, the app is fetching more data, and I can see some connection between volume of Cache Data and amount of items that was fetched, when all data from server was loaded cache size is around 40mb and don't more. it's repeatable, I can clean all cache data, then scroll again through all items and again - 40MB of cache.

How can I prevent such a behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908638/4778343