# How do I delete my app cache when the app is exited?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

Is there any way to delete the cache of the app at exit as using Glide to load images in recylerview from different fragments and activities is generating a huge amount of cache to the App.(don,t want to use disk cache strategies of glide as caches are required during runtime)

Comment: Are you looking to explicitly delete files added only by Glide in cache ?

Comment: Is that possible??

Comment: I'm not sure, I briefly checked Glide souce code, but found nothing useful.
You can clear all cache with this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908638/2930834

Comment: Consider taking action on this question as this is duplicate question. Marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Cache in Android Application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for delete cache of your own application then simply delete your cache directory and it's all done!

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}


public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```