# How to clear app cache on exit pressed button?

Tags: java, android, caching

I just want to clear app cache on exit when pressed, tried many answers out there but got errors and didn't work, so here is my code:

```
if (Config.ENABLE_EXIT_DIALOG) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.dialog_close_msg);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_option_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });

            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_option_rate_us, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    final String appName = getPackageName();
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appName)));
                    }

                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });

            dialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.dialog_option_more, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_more_apps))));

                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

got solved, i think it's old way but it's working fine found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically) 
i actually used his question code at the end of the my mainActivity file and it worked like a charm, though i guess it's an old way but it's ok.
and here is the code

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    clearApplicationData();
}

public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("EEEEEERRRRRRROOOOOOORRRR", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```