# How to delete only the http cache in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am currently caching a http response (json) in my app and then storing an audio file inside app directory. In a specific scenario, I would like to force http to query the server instead of using the cache.  I tried deleting the cache by following steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically) post, but it deletes everything inside the app folder (including audio files).

Is there any way to delete only the http cache?

Comment: How are you caching the HTTP response?

Comment: You won't have answer, without information above.

Comment: @Zun: while making the http connection, I am using connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + maxStale) to cache it.  maxStale is set to 7 days.