# App Size Still same After delete Captured Images

Tags: android

I am working on android app which capture Images and send it to server  when internet available then delete these images

every thing works fine but when when capture image app size increase and when delete it app size still same

to understand me
suppose that app size when install it is 9MB

then I capture Image with size 5MB

then app size Increase to 14MB

then delete Image

then app Size should be 9MB Again
but that not happened it still 14

and when take another image size increase and increase ..

Any Help How to maintain app Size ?

Answer (score 1):

You should delete cache files ..
Because if you're uploading to server , then you must delete the catch file also along with the original file .
Please check the below link , for how to clean cache files .
[Clear Cache in Android Application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908189/clear-cache-in-android-application-programmatically)