# clearApplicationUserData minimizes the app

Tags: android, activity-manager

I want to erase the data of my app programatically. I've found the method [clearApplicationUserData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#clearApplicationUserData()). But when I run it, the app minimizes itself. That is, the app goes to background, like when it is pressed the home button. This is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    ((ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .clearApplicationUserData();
} else {
        // TODO
}
```

**There is some way to erase data using this method without minimizing the app?**

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Because I want to erase the data of my app programatically. This method is in the API. Can't I use it?  =)

Comment: What do you mean by app minimization?

Comment: You should probably store your app files under a known path and then just remove this folder when you need to.

Comment: I have the same issue, and it's not minimization, the application is being shut down.  FWIW I'm using it to clear all saved settings between installations of beta releases, because we aren't supporting data upgrade paths.

Comment: It's odd that `clearApplicationUserData` has a return value. What could you possibly do with it if the process is gone?

Answer (score 6):

Method **ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()** will erase all your app's data, and kill the app process directly without any warnings. I check the documentation and the source, it seems not like a bug but designed to work like that. I have some speculations as below:

1. This method is designed for completely reset your application. Maybe you can provide your users a completely reset option.
2. This method is designed for testing convinience (you can reset the app without reinstalling it).

If you want to implemet your own method to manage your app's data. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069679/4044704) maybe helpful.

Comment: What's interesting is that after a few seconds of running this, the `onNewToken` override of my `FirebaseMessagingService` implementation got executed. Do you know if this method keeps the app's services running?

Comment: As the firebase doc explaned.[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) This service regist an intent filter("com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT").When your app totally closed but then reseives this kind of intent, The service will restart to handle it.Hope this will help you @AliAvci.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));

                }
            }
        }
    }
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
```

Comment: ^ https://hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically