# saving and multiple update firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I need to modify User's profile in my app. I save 2 images in Firebase Storage and I must save new informations of User in two nodes of Firebase Database.(Users and Events-eventsID-author)
This is my Firebase console:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- Users
         |
         --- uid
                |
                --- name: "name"        
                |
                --- city: "Campobasso" 
                |                    
                --- url_photo_small: "urlStorage"
                |                    
                --- url_photo_large: "urlStorage"
    --- Events
         |
         --- eventsID
                |
                --- author
                          |
                          --- uid
                          |
                          --- name: "name"  
                          |
                          --- city: "Campobasso"       
                          |
                          --- url_photo_small: "urlStorage"
                          |                    
                          --- url_photo_large: "urlStorage"
    --- UsersEvents
         |
         --- uid
                |
                --- eventsID:true
```

This is my code to update

```
private ArrayList<String> eventi = new ArrayList<>();
```

..

```
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


//I load in eventi the events that contains the user's data and that I must update. 
    rootRef.child("UsersEvents").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        eventi.add(data.getKey());
                        Log.d(TAG,data.getKey());
                        updateEventForAuthor(eventi);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });


  final Map<String,Object> userDataEvents= new HashMap<>();


    //I use userDataEvents for update author in events
    userDataEvents.put("uid",uid);
    userDataEvents.put("name",name.getText().toString());
    userDataEvents.put("city",citta.getText().toString());

    //firebaseUpdate is the data to save in Users node
    firebaseUpdate.put("/Users/"+uid+"/uid",uid);
    firebaseUpdate.put("/Users/"+uid+"/name",name.getText().toString());
    firebaseUpdate.put("/Users/"+uid+"/city",citta.getText().toString());



    StorageReference path = storeRef.child(uid).child("pics").child("profile");

//I save the first image, take its url and I save the data in Events and Users.           path.child("small"+uid+".jpg").putFile(uri_image_small).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        url_image = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        userDataEvents.put("url_photo_small",url_image);
                        firebaseUpdate.put("/Users/"+uid+"/url_photo_small",url_image);
//I save user's data in every events associated to him
                        if(eventi.size()!= 0){
                            for(int i=0;i<eventi.size();i++){
                                firebaseUpdate.put("/Events/"+eventi.get(i)+"/author",userDataEvents);
                            }
                        }
                        //Update user's data
                        rootRef.updateChildren(firebaseUpdate);
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload eseguito small..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Errore durante Upload Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

//I save the second image and update data in Users and in Events          
path.child("large"+uid+".jpg").putFile(uri_image_large).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        url_image = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        userDataEvents.put("url_photo_large",url_image);
                        firebaseUpdate.put("/Users/"+uid+"/url_photo_large",url_image);

                        if(eventi.size()!= 0){
                            for(int i=0;i<eventi.size();i++){
                                firebaseUpdate.put("/Events/"+eventi.get(i)+"/author",userDataEvents);
                            }
                        }
                        //Aggiorna il nodo user
                        rootRef.updateChildren(firebaseUpdate);            
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload eseguito small..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Errore durante Upload Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Where

```
private void updateEventForAuthor(ArrayList<String> eventi) {
        this.eventi = eventi;
    }
```

Is there another way? When I use the app the data are saved but sometimes every photo is load on every events and sometimes there is event not updated. My apologies for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of ways. The matter was that the photo remained in the cache. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898278/6166244).

Answer (score 0):

use **addChildEventListener** in `onChildChanged` method you can check the updated event